# update query with subselects from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

I'm trying to create a query to update the `rank` field of all the records in the table, based on values from the same table.

I managed to get a working `SELECT` query that calculates the rank, but I'm having a hard time converting it to an `UPDATE`. This is the query:

```
SELECT
  ((views_count + comments_count) * (172800 / elapsed)) AS rank
FROM (
  SELECT
    p.views_count,
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.createdAt)) AS elapsed,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` AS c WHERE c.photo_id = p.id) AS comments_count
  FROM `photos` AS p
) AS m
```

How can I implant it in an `UPDATE` query, to update each record's `rank` value?

Thanks! :)

### EDIT:

My DB structure:

```
[Photo]
id
user_id
views_count
rank
createdAt

[Comment]
id
photo_id
content
```

Comment: can you post the structure. This can be achieved by a join

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but something like this should work:

```
UPDATE `photos`
FROM (
   SELECT id
        , (views_count + comments_count) * (172800 / elapsed) AS rank
   FROM (
      SELECT p.id
           , p.views_count
           , (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) 
              - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.createdAt)) AS elapsed
           , (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM `comments` AS c 
              WHERE c.photo_id = p.id) AS comments_count
      FROM `photos` AS p
      ) AS m
   ) AS z
SET rank=z.rank
WHERE `photos`.id=z.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write your new ranks to a temporary table and use that to update the original table. try

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tbl AS (
   SELECT ((views_count + comments_count) * (172800 / elapsed)) AS rank, m.id
      FROM (SELECT
         p.views_count,
         (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.createdAt)) AS elapsed,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` AS c WHERE c.photo_id = p.id) AS comments_count
         FROM `photos` AS p
      ) AS m);
```

and then

```
UPDATE photos, tmp_tbl SET photos.rank = tmp_tbl.rank WHERE photos.id=tmp_tbl.id;
```

and finally

```
DROP TABLE tmp_tbl;
```

[See this simliar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-temporary-table-from-select-statement-without-using-create-table)