# i cannot update a column by using a cloumn in the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate letter grade by using average column.

I tried to do it with this code:

```
UPDATE students
SET letter_grade='BA' 
WHERE (average- (select AVG(average)from   students )) > 20 
AND (average-(select AVG(average)from students)) < 25;
```

But it gives the following error: `you cant specify target table 'students' for update if FROM clause.`

It seems mysql does not allow update a table by using select from same table. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE students
SET letter_grade='BA'
GROUP BY average HAVING (average - avg(average)) > 20
AND (average - avg(average)) < 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select into a temporary table:
    [Create a temporary table in a SELECT statement without a separate CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table/5859469#5859469)
and then update with a select from the temporary.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE avgs( select students.id, average-AVG(average) as a from students);
UPDATE students SET letter_grade='BA' 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a FROM avgs 
                  WHERE students.id =avgs.id AND -20 < a AND a < 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do it as two queries, something like

```
declare average_average float
set average_average = AVG(average) from students 
Update students Set Letter_grade = 'BA' 
where (average - average_average) > 20 and (average - average_average) < 25
```

assuming average is a floating point field