# Create a global temporary table in mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, create-table

I would like to create the equivalent of this query (Oracle) in **MySQL**
Can anyone help?

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TEST
(
  id   VARCHAR2(50),
  id_age  NUMBER(38)
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Comment: Is this any help? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42766/creating-a-global-temp-table-in-mysql

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful, you can mention the TEMPORARY keyword in your create statement? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table