# sql - how to retrieve values which dont belong to a table

Tags: mysql, sql

So basically it was given to me a list of around 300 values (numbers).
And i need to modify a parameter for all of them.
I did a basic query (example below) and i only found 270 from this 300 which was given to me.
   `select count(*) from table where field in('1','2','3','4','5','6');`

My question is, how can i see which values (in this case are 30 values) are not present on the table?

This is a live system so i shouldnt create anything there or change.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If they are numbers, then you should not use single quotes.

Comment: Do you have a numbers table?  Are you opposed to creating any tables in the environment, or just don't want to disturb existing items?

Comment: Yes, this field contains only numbers (VARCHAR2(32).
And i would like not to create any new tables on this schema.

Answer (score 3):

You can add another table holding your set. Let's name it *set_table* with one column named *set_key*.

Insert your set into that table; will now look like this:

```
set_key
----
1
2
...
```

Now try this

```
SELECT `set_key` FROM `set_table` WHERE `set_key` not in (select value from your_other_table where 1);
```

This should give you the keys that are in your set but not in your table.

**Example:**

Your set is *(1,2,42)*

Your table contains values with *1* and *2*

The subselect `select value from your_other_table` will give you *1* and *2*. The whole query will now look like this: `SELECT`set_key`FROM`set_table`WHERE`set_key`not in (1, 2);` That'll give you (*42*) as result.

Comment: Totally incorrect. Read question one more time. OP wants to find values from **list** which are **not present in the table**. You're suggesting opposite - find records from table not present in list.

Comment: Its is not. I already tried that one before making this post.
This will give me the remain of values on this table... which are other 300 records...

Comment: woops- question title confused me, wait a sec

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to do it without creating a new table on live system? Like somehow creating a virtual table with my list and compare to the full list of the table and see which arent present?

Comment: @ApolloWork should work w/ temporary tables, too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table for temp tables

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other records in the table besides those 300 ? If not , `select count(*) from table where field not in('1','2','3','4','5','6');`

Comment: Yes, the full table have around 600 records.

Comment: Same as answer from m02ph3u5  - you're suggesting opposite to the OP requirement - finding records from table not present in list, but he wants to  find values from list which are not present in the table.