# Why does ExtractValue() fail in an UPDATE and succeed in a SELECT?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I execute this query...

```
UPDATE tbl a,
(SELECT id, EXTRACTVALUE(content, '//a[contains(text(), "View")]/@href') AS url FROM tbl) b
SET tbl.`url` = b.`url`
```

...I see this error:

```
Error Code: 1525
Incorrect XML value: 'parse error at line 57 pos 195: '</div>' unexpected (END-OF-INPUT wanted)'
```

But when I execute this query...

```
SELECT id, EXTRACTVALUE(content, '//a[contains(text(), "View")]/@href') AS url FROM tbl
```

...the query succeeds.

Why does the UPDATE query fail where the standalone SELECT query succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem, and while I don't know the answer to the question as of "why", I can provide a workaround: put your sub-query's result into a [temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table), for example as such (pseudo-code):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (SELECT id, EXTRACTVALUE(content, '//a[contains(text(), "View")]/@href') AS url FROM tbl);
    
UPDATE tbl a, temp b
SET tbl.`url` = b.`url`
```

You can reference it this way as multi-table update, or use an inner-join, it seems to work both ways just fine.