# Filter table before applying query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table called `push_message_info` that I want to filter and then calculate some results. The query to get the results is:

```
SELECT p.pending, s.success, t.total
FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) AS pending FROM push_message_info WHERE served < total) AS p,
    (SELECT count(*) AS success FROM push_message_info WHERE served = total) AS s,
    (SELECT count(*) AS total FROM push_message_info) AS t
;
```

And the thing is I would like to count only the newest entries. Since it has a datetime field called `submit_date` I've thought something like this would work:

```
SELECT p.pending, s.success, t.total
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM push_message_info WHERE DATE(submit_date) > '2017-05-14') AS filtered
    (SELECT count(*) AS pending FROM filtered WHERE served < total) AS p,
    (SELECT count(*) AS success FROM filtered WHERE served = total) AS s,
    (SELECT count(*) AS total FROM filtered) AS t
;
```

But it throws me the error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'unifiedpush.filtered' doesn't exist

How can I filter/limit the original table so that I can apply other queries on that new table?

Comment: does it have to be `unifiedpush.push_message_info` and can't be `push_message_info`?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it really doesn't matter, I erased it for the sake of simplicity but forget it in the second query, I'll remove it now.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't see what example could I add, since the question is about the query itself not the data.

Comment: Jose, you seem determined to discourage others from helping. It's working.

Comment: Quite the opposite @Strawberry , I must've explained the problem very bad, probably due to my lack of knowledge in this topic, but really I don't understand why I'm discouraging others to help.

Comment: I've suggested a way to explain the problem better. I'm puzzled by your resistance - but presumably you know better than the rest of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your query is the scope of the filtered alias: it is not visible from the other subqueries.

If you really really want to have it, you can create a view:

```
create view filtered as SELECT * FROM push_message_info WHERE DATE(submit_date) > '2017-05-14';

SELECT p.pending, s.success, t.total
FROM
    (SELECT count(*) AS pending FROM filtered WHERE served < total) AS p,
    (SELECT count(*) AS success FROM filtered WHERE served = total) AS s,
    (SELECT count(*) AS total FROM filtered) AS t;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, although I understand this might not the most efficient approach, now I understand why my query wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

Your query isn't good in general.
Instead of making all these subqueries, you can to that with one simple query.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN served < total THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pending,
    SUM(CASE WHEN served = total THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS served,
    COUNT(*) as total
FROM push_message_info
WHERE DATE(submit_date) > '2017-05-14';
```

I've switched `count`s (except `total`) with `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` which let you do conditional counts.

Comment: Sorry you are not really answering what it's being asked.

Comment: It gives you data that you want. Tell me how it's not answering your question, so I can improve my anwer.

Comment: So what I would like to achieve is to filter the table and rename this view as "filtered". Once I got this "intermediate" table, apply queries on it. It's not about the output or the date, it's more about to understand how the subqueries work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can tell you how I have accomplished something like this. Try:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(served < total, 1, 0)) as pending,
       SUM(IF(served = total,1 ,0)) AS success,
       COUNT(*) as total
  FROM push_message_info
 WHERE DATE(submit_date) > '2017-05-14';
```

That should give you what you need...

Comment: This is not really what I want to know. By the way it fails.

Comment: Not sure why it fails. I don't have your data so I constructed it by eye but I just did a similar query and the if() function works fine. Could you perhaps elaborate on what you want your output to look like? As I read your SQL and your question, you want a count of [ending, success and total for new submissions... did I miss something?

Comment: I just saw the error. Remove the comma after total and it should work. That was a typo. Sorry

Comment: So the point isn't really the output. What I'd like to achieve is to "create" an "intermediate" table so I can run some queries on it. This "intermediate" table would be the result of filtering the dates.

Comment: Perhaps this might help? It talks about creating a temporary table from a select: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table).