# Getting the value of the previous query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that includes a number of query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()

BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM a;
    INSERT INTO b ...;          //use result a query
    UPDATE c ...;               //use result a query
    INSERT INTO d ...;          //use result a query
    SELECT * FROM d WHERE ...;  //use result a query
    INSERT INTO e ...;          //use result d query
    UPDATE a ...;               //use result d query

END 
$$
```

How can I get value from previous queries?

And

How can I detect if it was null?

Answer (score 3):

If you are inserting one row at a time  and you want the the most recent auto-incremented id, you can get the id using;

```
select last_insert_id()
```

This is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

If they are inserting multiple rows, then this can be a little bit trickier.

If you want to "return" a value from a `select`, use variables . . . either `:=` or `into`.

Comment: My first query is select. Then, by taking last_insert_id(), another user may be taken. And I do not just want an id

Comment: Can you please give me a small example?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use "temp table". It is temporary tables that you can create to store your data and perform query on it **as per that session**.

So, it could be something like this..

> ```
> DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE test()
>
> BEGIN
>
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTable_A AS (SELECT * FROM a)
>
> INSERT INTO b ...;          //use result tempTable_A  query
> UPDATE c ...;               //use result tempTable_A  query
> INSERT INTO d ...;          //use result tempTable_A  query
>
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTable_D AS (SELECT * FROM d) //use result tempTable_A  query
> INSERT INTO e ...;          //use result tempTable_D  query
> UPDATE a ...;               //use result tempTable_D  query
>
>
>
> END  $$
> ```

Example could be found here:
[Create a temporary table in a SELECT statement without a separate CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table)

Documentation link:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html