# select all rows for one user in one row mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table which has the below structure

```
id,username,attribute,value,realname,birthdate,phone
```

and I have these records in the table

```
1,john,Cleartext-Password,ss,johnsmith,1/1/1990,9786865754
2,john,Expiration,20/1/2018,null,null,null
```

I want to write a query that shows the below result

```
username|password|expir     |realname|birthdate|phone 
john    |ss      |20/1/2018 |johnsmith|1/1/1990|9786865754
```

I tried using the query mentioned below. But I don't seem to get the desired result.

```
select c1.username ,c1.value as 'password',c1.adsoyad,c1.telefon,c1.email,c1.dtarih,c1.tcno,c2.value as 'expired' from radcheck c1 INNER join radcheck c2 on c1.username=c2.username and c1.attribute='Cleartext-Password' and c2.attribute='Expiration' and c1.username='john' and c2.username='john'
```

Comment: _cleartext-password_ Pooh! Don't do that..

Comment: Your two records of sample data do not make any sense to me.  By the way, are you storing your dates as text?  Don't do that; it will cause problems down the road.

Comment: this is database for freeradius server so I can not edit it

Comment: don't save plain password. Use password hashing. Also records are in table? Or in text file? Where is db connection code?Please add complete code

Comment: this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table

Comment: Can you paste the actual database contents here from MySQL? The records are pretty confusing

Comment: in my table the attribute can has more than one value for one user (for example :user1, cleartext-password,xxx,user user,1/1/1990,9768756; here the attribute cleartext-password determine user's password in other hand expiration determine when user's account will expir and I want all this info in one row

Comment: `select c1.username, c1.value as 'password', c2.value as 'expir', c1.realname, c1.birthdate, c1.phone from radcheck c1 INNER join radcheck c2 on c1.username=c2.username and c1.attribute='Cleartext-Password' and c2.attribute='Expiration' where c1.username='john'`

Comment: In your example cleartext-password and expiration are in lowercase while in your query they're not. Is it an error in your example ?

Comment: thank you for your help but some times user has one attribute Cleartext-Password and don't has  Expiration attribute so this query not show any thing and I want to display cleartextpassword and realname and birthdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does conditional aggregation do what you want?

```
select c.username,
       max(case when c.attribute = 'password' then c.value end) as password,
       max(case when c.attribute = 'expiration' then c.value end) as expiration,
       max(c.realname) as realname, min(c.birthdate) as birthdate, max(c.phone) as phone
from radcheck c
group by username
```