# mysql create temp table column using select command

Tags: mysql

i need to create a temporary table which column name will generate dynamically using a select command (mean: the value of another table.). But when i run the command then the temp table created with the value not the column name.
i have tried as below:

SELECT ColVal FROM tableA

TableA

```
------------------------
ColName | ColVal 
------------------------
id      | 1
----------------------
Name    | Test
----------------------
Age     |25
---------------------
```

Now , i need to create Temp table B which column name will be as below

TableB

```
--------------
id| Name| Age|
--------------
```

I have tried by the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  TableB as (select ColName  from TableA)
```

it's not give me the actual output. it create the table like:

TableB

```
-----------------
ColName
-----------------
id
--------
Name
--------
Age
--------
```

Comment: You can try pivoting on the `id` column to transform rows into columns.  Just Google "pivot query SQL" and you will find help.

Comment: May be duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table

Comment: problem is . the field is dynamic, mean: in here i write only 3 value. it could be 3 to 30 different name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is the best way to do it, but you can run dynamically constructed sql. You can do something like that:

```
SELECT  CONCAT("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TableB (", 
               group_concat( CONCAT(ColName, " VARCHAR(50)")), ");")
               INTO @Expression
FROM TableA;

PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression;
EXECUTE myquery;
```

@Expression will be equal to: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TableB (id VARCHAR(50),Name VARCHAR(50),Age VARCHAR(50));`

Comment: It might be useful include a distinct clause in the group_concat in case of repeating tokens  ie group_concat(distinct